# ExoPlayer - playing multiple videos

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I'm tying to play videos from a Firebase Listadapter.  When the user clicks on the list they a video plays, and upon finishing the activity finishes, and they return to the original list.

When the click on the second video it starts the ExoPlayer activity, but won't play the video.  If they press back and select the original video it will play fine.

```
public String mTastingWineID;
public String tastingWineId;
public String mWineVideoID;
public String tastingWineVideoId;
private DataSource.Factory mediaDataSourceFactory;
private boolean isPlaying = false;
public int mVideoResource;
public Uri videoUri;
private static final String TAG = "WineMediaActivity";
private static final DefaultBandwidthMeter BANDWIDTH_METER = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
private SimpleExoPlayer player;
private SimpleExoPlayerView mVideoView;
private ComponentListener componentListener;
private long playbackPostiion;
private int currentWindow;
private boolean playWhenReady = true;
private BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
public Firebase wineMediaUrl;
public ValueEventListener wineMediaUrlListener;
private MediaControllerCompat mediaControllerCompat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.analytics_media_wine_information);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    mTastingWineID = bundle.getString(Constants.WINE_ID);
    tastingWineId = mTastingWineID.toString();
    mWineVideoID = bundle.getString(Constants.WINE_VIDEO_ID);
    tastingWineVideoId = mWineVideoID.toString();

    if (player != null){
        player.release();
    }

    getCurrentVideo();

}

public void getCurrentVideo(){
    wineMediaUrl = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL).child(FIREBASE_LOCATION_WINE_DETAILS).child(tastingWineId).child(WINE_MEDIA).child(tastingWineVideoId).child("wineVideoUrl");
    wineMediaUrlListener = wineMediaUrl.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            componentListener = new ComponentListener();
            mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
            mVideoView.requestFocus();


            Object tempVideoFiles = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String str = tempVideoFiles.toString();
            videoUri = Uri.parse(str);

            if (videoUri != null) {
                initializePlayer();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(WineMediaActivity.this, "No Video Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    mediaDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "mediaPlayerSample"), (TransferListener<? super DataSource>) bandwidthMeter);


}

private class ComponentListener implements ExoPlayer.EventListener, VideoRendererEventListener, AudioRendererEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        String stateString;
        switch (playbackState) {
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE:
                stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE";
                break;
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
                stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE";
                break;
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
                stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE";
                break;
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
                stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE";
                releasePlayer();
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                stateString = "UNKNOWN_STATE";
                break;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "changed state to: " + stateString + " play when ready: " + playWhenReady);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekProcessed() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioEnabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioSessionId(int audioSessionId) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioDecoderInitialized(String decoderName, long initializedTimestampMs, long initializationDurationMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioInputFormatChanged(Format format) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioSinkUnderrun(int bufferSize, long bufferSizeMs, long elapsedSinceLastFeedMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioDisabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoDecoderInitialized(String decoderName, long initializedTimestampMs, long initializationDurationMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoInputFormatChanged(Format format) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDroppedFrames(int count, long elapsedMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRenderedFirstFrame(Surface surface) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoDisabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }
}

private void initializePlayer() {

    if (player == null) {
        TrackSelection.Factory adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this), new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory), new DefaultLoadControl());
        player.addListener(componentListener);
        player.setVideoDebugListener(componentListener);
        player.setAudioDebugListener(componentListener);
        mVideoView.setPlayer(player);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPostiion);
    }

    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri, mediaDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
    player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);

}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void hideSystemUi() {
    mVideoView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}

private void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        playbackPostiion = player.getCurrentPosition();
        currentWindow = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
        playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
        player.removeListener(componentListener);
        mVideoView.setPlayer(null);
        player.setVideoListener(null);
        player.setVideoDebugListener(null);
        player.setAudioDebugListener(null);
        player.release();
        player = null;

        if (wineMediaUrlListener != null) {
            wineMediaUrl.removeEventListener(wineMediaUrlListener);
            wineMediaUrlListener = null;
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releasePlayer();
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    releasePlayer();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releasePlayer();
}
```

Apologies for the code, I'm newish to coding and hoping someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code is fine - the error was in the upload of videos, they were overwriting the previous video meaning the previous one wouldn't play.